# How can i change label "Sort by" in Vuetify's data table?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

The label is visible only in the mobile view at the top of the `v-data-table`. I've read the documentation and there's no such a prop that can modify the "Sort by" label.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

We can easily do this by adding `headerProps` to the `data` option like:

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data () {
    return {
      headerProps: {
        sortByText: "Custom Sort By Text"
      },
      headers: [
        //...
      ],
      items: [
        //...
      ]  
    }
  },
})
```

and then updating the template like:

```
<v-data-table
  :headers="headers"
  :items="items"
  :items-per-page="5"
  class="elevation-1"
  :header-props="headerProps"
>      
</v-data-table>
```

Now, in mobile view instead of showing default `"Sort by"` label, it will show `"Custom Sort By Text"` and you can modify it as you need.

Comment: hello! how have you found the solution? I was looking for in the official documentation but I havent found anything https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/data-tables/#data-tables

Comment: Yes, in the past I had also faced the same issue. So, I had to review the vuetify github code and could easily see the option for it here: [VDataTableHeaderMobile.ts](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/blob/master/packages/vuetify/src/components/VDataTable/VDataTableHeaderMobile.ts#L12)

Comment: Wow! I think It would be interesting that the official documentation includes this info! Thank you for your help!

Comment: @palaѕн , thank you man!! you saved my day!! but there is some issues! it gives me `vue warn` and `Mismatching ChildNodes vs VNodes` console errors. and it only shows on mobile view. i know it's just a warning but sometimes these warnings broke my website. what should i do?